# ASP Classic - Column sorting with ASC and DESC

Tags: sorting, asp-classic

I have given a table and I need to add support (provide sorting function to sort the report table column record in Ascending and Decending direction) where the user select the **Sort by** option at the report table and choose either **ASC** or **DESC**.

Can you help on that..a simple example will do.

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of altering the *query*? (And, as such, what has been tried?)

Comment: Hi, I havent try anything yet, just want to get some picture because im still a beginner. Can u give me some example?

Comment: More important: from where do you get your data? From a database using a query? From a file? Or just an HTML table? If database then alter the query, if not try @JonP's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Personally i'd sort it client side using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the [table sorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

Comment: This is interesting Jon, will try on this and get to u as soon. Tq